# Trying to download m3u8/HLS stream with errors

Tags: ffmpeg, video, download

I am trying to download a HLS video and I'm receiving errors. From what I can tell by Googling it has something to do with encryption? But I can't find a way to confirm that or a way around it. I have tried it both with and without my username and password in the URL. I was hoping I could have some help with figuring out the correct commands to use.
Thanks in advance!

```
ffmpeg -i https:\u002F\u002Fcloudflarestream.com\u002FeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJraWQiOiJiMjU5ZDVlMGNmNjMzMDVkOWU0MDYxNjYxNzJjMTVhZCIsInN1YiI6IjQ4MTBmMjFjYTkxMzMyNGRkMTBjYzJmM2RjOTFmYjkxIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc4NTg2NDI4LCJkb3dubG9hZGFibGUiOnRydWUsImFjY2Vzc1J1bGVzIjpbXX0.CeLLYbhjyezE8yC4Cu_tNf7OfvHl9gbd0rGmpGLy_aLxWWwSeoCUYZU5V7eYRNXYKKhugU1MZvs8etWDYamjVtpq3fldyVI9p6MkTJYl26D4Qb8XIlUL9VnpWbjWgNMYwLF_okPtausmMNVe7m9mP7A4jtnF2fTm0-Ql0j_F_98oGMGLV9cWiAh9TZY1cRAmaNFALSZL9i_rTuX7WCukqQFiMxcJVHmXFxqUpItaWMpNgMBB1V6T7cR38GbQ9PH_cBkpXtN4NHnFQ_gT2XDnx81Fs0CTwTyrIgwhcNDF0cDeWn9Jz-NfAge4fqY63ZgPk0bBeinfJzhx3LScXVojvA\u002Fmanifest\u002Fvideo.m3u8 -map p:6 -c copy -t 60 -f segment -segment_list out.list out%03d.ts
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2_6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
[tcp @ 0x12d605af0] Port missing in uri
```

With credentials:

```
ffmpeg -i https:\USERNAME:PASSWORD@u002F\u002Fcloudflarestream.com\u002FeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJraWQiOiJiMjU5ZDVlMGNmNjMzMDVkOWU0MDYxNjYxNzJjMTVhZCIsInN1YiI6IjQ4MTBmMjFjYTkxMzMyNGRkMTBjYzJmM2RjOTFmYjkxIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc4NTg2NDI4LCJkb3dubG9hZGFibGUiOnRydWUsImFjY2Vzc1J1bGVzIjpbXX0.CeLLYbhjyezE8yC4Cu_tNf7OfvHl9gbd0rGmpGLy_aLxWWwSeoCUYZU5V7eYRNXYKKhugU1MZvs8etWDYamjVtpq3fldyVI9p6MkTJYl26D4Qb8XIlUL9VnpWbjWgNMYwLF_okPtausmMNVe7m9mP7A4jtnF2fTm0-Ql0j_F_98oGMGLV9cWiAh9TZY1cRAmaNFALSZL9i_rTuX7WCukqQFiMxcJVHmXFxqUpItaWMpNgMBB1V6T7cR38GbQ9PH_cBkpXtN4NHnFQ_gT2XDnx81Fs0CTwTyrIgwhcNDF0cDeWn9Jz-NfAge4fqY63ZgPk0bBeinfJzhx3LScXVojvA\u002Fmanifest\u002Fvideo.m3u8 -map p:6 -c copy -t 60 -f segment -segment_list out.list out%03d.ts
zsh: no matches found: https:USERNAME:PASSWORD@u002Fu002Fcloudflarestream.comu002FeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJraWQiOiJiMjU5ZDVlMGNmNjMzMDVkOWU0MDYxNjYxNzJjMTVhZCIsInN1YiI6IjQ4MTBmMjFjYTkxMzMyNGRkMTBjYzJmM2RjOTFmYjkxIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc4NTg2NDI4LCJkb3dubG9hZGFibGUiOnRydWUsImFjY2Vzc1J1bGVzIjpbXX0.CeLLYbhjyezE8yC4Cu_tNf7OfvHl9gbd0rGmpGLy_aLxWWwSeoCUYZU5V7eYRNXYKKhugU1MZvs8etWDYamjVtpq3fldyVI9p6MkTJYl26D4Qb8XIlUL9VnpWbjWgNMYwLF_okPtausmMNVe7m9mP7A4jtnF2fTm0-Ql0j_F_98oGMGLV9cWiAh9TZY1cRAmaNFALSZL9i_rTuX7WCukqQFiMxcJVHmXFxqUpItaWMpNgMBB1V6T7cR38GbQ9PH_cBkpXtN4NHnFQ_gT2XDnx81Fs0CTwTyrIgwhcNDF0cDeWn9Jz-NfAge4fqY63ZgPk0bBeinfJzhx3LScXVojvAu002Fmanifestu002Fvideo.m3u8
```

Comment: It's not encryption, I think the first commands are wrong. The entire string `https: ... video.m3u8` is an URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). Web URIs use forward-, not backslashes, and string `u002F` translates to `/`. Backslash isn't used AFAIK anywhere but with Windows so I don't think it should be there. The message says "Port missing", and ports are denoted with web URIs with `:`. So `https://acme.com:1234` is connecting to acme.com using port 1234. The start showing the protocol should be continuous, so `https:username:pass//` can't work.

Comment: Your "with credentials" case accidentally put the credentials in the wrong place: it should be in the form: `https://username:password@host.example.com/path/to/filename.m3u8`, but you have it as `https:username:password@//host.example.com/path/to/filename.m3u8`

Comment: Adding to @Spiff's... if a port is required, it'd be `https://username:password@host.example.com:1234/path/to/filename.m3u8`.